# Saving a new record to CloudKit on the watch never completes

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, watchos

The following code is identical both in the WatchKitExtension ContentView and in iOS in the ContentView.  Running WatchOS 8 and iOS 15.

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit
import os

let logger = Logger(subsystem: "com.companyname", category: "watchkittest")

struct ContentView: View {
    let db = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.companyname.cloudKitTest").publicCloudDatabase
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            logger.notice("button tapped, attempting to save a new record")
            Task {
                do {
                    let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: UUID().uuidString)
                    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "cities", recordID: recordID)
                    record["name"] = "Chicago"

                    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [record], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
                    operation.savePolicy = CKModifyRecordsOperation.RecordSavePolicy.allKeys
                    logger.notice("about to call try await ...")
                    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) in
                        operation.modifyRecordsResultBlock = {result in
                            switch result {
                            case .success:
                                logger.notice("Record cities with ID: \(record.recordID) was successfully saved")
                                continuation.resume()
                            case .failure(let error):
                                logger.error("Record cities with ID: \(record.recordID) failed to be saved with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                            }
                        }
                        db.add(operation)
                    })
                } catch {
                    logger.error("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Create Record")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When running on the watch, the save never completes with either an error or success.  My logs look like this.

```
2021-10-21 09:08:45.321128-0500 WatchKitTest3 WatchKit Extension[685:83322] [watchkittest] button tapped, attempting to save a new record
2021-10-21 09:08:45.330270-0500 WatchKitTest3 WatchKit Extension[685:83322] [watchkittest] about to call try await ...
```

When running on the phone in iOS 15 it works just fine.

```
2021-10-21 09:19:36.425823-0500 CloudKitTest4[795:88715] [watchkittest] button tapped, attempting to save a new record
2021-10-21 09:19:36.433862-0500 CloudKitTest4[795:88715] [watchkittest] about to call try await ...
2021-10-21 09:19:36.727816-0500 CloudKitTest4[795:89052] [watchkittest] Record cities with ID: <CKRecordID: 0x283980e80; recordName=ACAA7ADC-DE24-4B46-9209-49EC1BF512F5, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__> was successfully saved
```

Am I doing something wrong on the Watch side or is this likely a bug?

Watch has good wifi connectivity.

Comment: Just out of curiocity...  Why are you using `CKModifyRecordsOperation` just in order to save one record?  If you use `CKDatabase`'s `save(_:completionHandler:)`, it will be pretty simpler.

Comment: Ah, the code I pulled this from in my main app uses this same functionality for creating a new record or updating a currently existing record. This code handles both cases.

Comment: What is the watch extension targets container app (in the capability section)? Make sure it references the iOS host app.

Comment: This is running as a stand alone watch app, although the behavior is the same if attached to a companion iOS app